# MapKit always centers on userlocation

Tags: ios, dictionary, geolocation

I have a map that zooms appropriately to the current location on load, but then doesn't allow you to pan around the map without it immediately zooming back in on the user location. I have been playing around with tracking mode but haven't gotten the right fix.. Here is some code, I appreciate the help.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    mapViewuno.delegate = self;
    mapViewuno.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapViewuno.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    indexValue = 0;
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mapAddress" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intID];
    NSLog(@"array : %@",[dict objectForKey:strID]);
    [contentArray removeAllObjects];
    [contentArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:strID]];
    [contentArray retain];
    [self zoomToUserLocation:mapViewuno.userLocation];
}
- (void)zoomToUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!userLocation)
        return;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(.5, .5);
    region = [mapViewuno regionThatFits:region];
    [mapViewuno setRegion:region animated:YES];
    counter = 0;

    [mapViewuno removeAnnotations:mapViewuno.annotations];

    if([contentArray count] != 0)
    {
        for(indexValue = 0; indexValue<[contentArray count];indexValue++)
        {
            FirstAnnotation *obj=[[FirstAnnotation alloc]init];

            obj.latitude = [[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"lattitude"] floatValue];
            obj.longitude = [[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

            obj.titleName=[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Title"];

            obj.Address = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Address"];

            obj.Phone = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Phone"];

            obj.intTag = indexValue;
            [mapViewuno addAnnotation:obj];
        }
        if ([mapViewuno.annotations count] == 0) return;

                //        [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
    }

}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [self zoomToUserLocation:userLocation];
}
```

Comment: Does it stop zooming back on the user location if you remove `didUpdateUserLocation`?

Answer (score 1):

This part is causing the problem:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [self zoomToUserLocation:userLocation];
}
```

Every time the mapview's location manager gets a new fix (i.e. every second or so) the mapview calls that delegate method which in turn calls your method to zoom. Put in a `BOOL` like `zoomedToUserLocation` and set it to `NO` at init time, then to `YES` when it hits `zoomToUserLocation` the first time.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect since. I apologize I am a bit new to Xcode could you show me how to write that Bool function?

Comment: There isn't really space here to explain it, but you'll need a BOOL instance variable or @property to store the value. Check out the Big Nerd Ranch Objective C Programming book and you'll get a great foundation of Obj-C.

Comment: I tried declaring this BOOL property: @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL zoomedToUserLocation;   But cannot seem to get it called in order to take place?